# Dynamically update the subscription to websocket

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, async-await, python-asyncio

```
    import asyncio
    import json
    import ssl
    import websockets
    from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
    import MarketDataFeed_pb2 as pb
    import upstox_client
    from cs50 import SQL
    
    # Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
    db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")
    
    websocket = None
    
    async def establish_connection(configuration):
        api_version = '2.0'
        api_instance = upstox_client.WebsocketApi(
            upstox_client.ApiClient(configuration))
        api_response = api_instance.get_market_data_feed_authorize(api_version)
    
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
        ssl_context.check_hostname = False
        ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    
        websocket = await websockets.connect(api_response.data.authorized_redirect_uri, ssl=ssl_context)
        print('Connection established')
        return websocket
    
    
    async def subscribe_instruments(websocket, mode, instruments):
        data = {
            "guid": "someguid",
            "method": "sub",
            "data": {"mode": mode, "instrumentKeys": instruments}
        }
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'))
        print("Subscribed to instruments: " + json.dumps(instruments))
    
    
    async def unsubscribe_instruments(websocket, mode, instruments):
        data = {
            "guid": "someguid",
            "method": "unsub",
            "data": {"mode": mode, "instrumentKeys": instruments}
        }
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'))
        print("Unsubscribed from instruments: " + json.dumps(instruments))
    
    
    async def receive_messages(websocket):
        try:
            while True:
                message = await websocket.recv()
                decoded_data = decode_protobuf(message)
                data_dict = MessageToDict(decoded_data)
                print(json.dumps(data_dict))
                # parsed_data= json.dumps(data_dict)
                # for instrument_name, instrument_data in parsed_data['feeds'].items():
                #     ltp = instrument_data['ltpc']['ltp']
                #     #next_function(instrument_name, ltp) # write a function to data
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("WebSocket connection is being gracefully shutdown.")
            await websocket.close()
    
    
    def decode_protobuf(buffer):
        feed_response = pb.FeedResponse()
        feed_response.ParseFromString(buffer)
        return feed_response
    
    
    async def main():
        global websocket
        mode = 'ltpc'
        # Configure OAuth2 access token for authorization
        configuration = upstox_client.Configuration()
        ACCESS_TOKEN = db.execute("SELECT ACCESS_TOKEN FROM credentials WHERE CLIENT_ID = 1")[0]["ACCESS_TOKEN"]
        configuration.access_token = ACCESS_TOKEN
    
        #configuration.access_token = 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
    
        # Establish WebSocket connection
        websocket = await establish_connection(configuration)
    
        
    
    async def main():
        global websocket
        mode = 'ltpc'
        # Configure OAuth2 access token for authorization
        configuration = upstox_client.Configuration()
        ACCESS_TOKEN = db.execute("SELECT ACCESS_TOKEN FROM credentials WHERE CLIENT_ID = 1")[0]["ACCESS_TOKEN"]
        configuration.access_token = ACCESS_TOKEN
    
        #configuration.access_token = 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
    
        # Establish WebSocket connection
        websocket = await establish_connection(configuration)
    
        # Start receiving messages in a separate task
        receiver_task = asyncio.create_task(receive_messages(websocket))
    
        # Subscribe to initial instruments and more as needed
        await subscribe_instruments(websocket, mode, ['NSE_INDEX|Nifty 50'])
            
        await receiver_task
    
    async def more_sub():
        global websocket
        mode = 'ltpc'
        # Example of subscribing to more instruments later
        await asyncio.sleep(3)  # Wait for some time or certain condition
        await subscribe_instruments(websocket, mode, ['NSE_FO|44797'])
    
        # Example of unsubscribing from an instruments
        await asyncio.sleep(3)  # Wait for some time or certain condition
        await unsubscribe_instruments(websocket, mode, ['NSE_INDEX|Nifty 50'])
    
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        asyncio.run(main())
```

this is the updated code but still i want to call a function to subscribe instrument . the above code will subscribe to the instrument and get ltp data . now i want to add more instrument on demand. so now i can subscribe to instrument but its in single main function i want to execute in separate function which lets me send subscription on demand.

if you know someone who can answer this. please do share this post